# Add feature to automatically add a notice to new questions

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

I added an answer to the question [Can there be done more to assure users that closing questions is not a Bad Thing?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/can-there-be-done-more-to-assure-users-that-closing-questions-is-not-a-bad-thing) and wanted to raise this as a new Meta-Post to discuss as [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4509/28789) and [dot_sp0t](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35529944#35529944) suggested. I had the idea for this answer because I am trying my best to help new users understand why questions are put on hold and that "on hold" is different from "closed and marked for deletion" by adding some standard texts if I see questions generating comments about VTC-ing and not about the possibility of it being reopened after edits. Most of the time I comment something like "Quick reminder: 'on hold' is different from 'closed'. A few edits could lead to your question being reopened. Please start by [stuff]."

As far as I know questions tagged "hard-science" get a special notice that only certain people can manually put there and remove.

**Is it possible to add a feature to automatically add such a notice, like the one on questions tagged "hard-science", to any new question?**

Mithrandir24601 and dot_Sp0T told me in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35529944#35529944) that currently there is no way to automatically add such a notice.

I was thinking about adding a notice along the lines of „This question is new and hasn’t been reviewed by the community until now. If you want to answer this question please make sure that it fits the sites guidelines. If this question does not fit the sites guidelines it will be put on hold for some time to allow the author to edit the question before reopening it for answers.“

This would automatically show the intention of „putting questions on hold“ for new users and it could also prevent some of the cases where new useres were answering very fast even if the question was not a good fit for the site at first. At the same time it would not be as invasive as generally putting the question on hold at first, though I like this idea of [SRM](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/proposal-all-questions-start-on-hold-for-1-hour).

It would be nice if questions with such a notice could go into a special Review-Queue so that experienced users can delete the message if the question fits the site. Or that the notice will be automatically deleted after one or two hours. Until then somebody experienced (probably) gave feedback on the question.

This feature could also be limited to new users and their first question on the site if this is easier to implement or fits the general way of StackExchange better. This way new users will get a notice when posting a question and when someone reviews the question in the normal 500 reputation [Review Queue for first posts/ late answers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) the notice could automatically be deleted, if the question is okay.

Comment: There already is a [first post](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts) review queue that has functionality not entirely unrelated to what you're looking for, although yes, I agree - something on top of that would potentially be good - perhaps if [no action needed] was selected or if the reviewer upvoted the question, the notice would go away?

Comment: Kind of related (since this is all tied into the idea of sanity checks for new questions): http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/4541/28